# Port Forwarding issue on Netgear D7000v2

Tags: router, portforwarding, dyndns

I have a weird problem. From my Netgear D7000v2 router (Firmware: V1.0.0.51_1.0.1) I have been trying to do port forwarding on certain ports. Previously I used to do the same thing from my BT router without any problem (quite experienced with the process). After DynDNS and port forwarding Whatever devices are connected to my Netgear Router (Home Wifi) can not access to the services but I can access those services from the internet (not from my home wifi). Anyone got any clue what I might have done wrong? Or is it a fault with the Router/Firmware? And I am sure it's got nothing to do with Firewall because its working from outside of the local network and I tried turning my server firewall off.

FYI I do not have any intention to flash the router with DDWRT.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Netgear D7000v2 does not support NAT loopback which would allow addressing a device on your LAN with it's WAN address.

eg: IP cam using LAN 192.168.0.200: 7045 is accessible from your browser but the same cam using it's WAN address https://anycamaddress.com:7045 is only accessible from outside your own local network.

Some Netgear routers, for example the R7000, does support NAT loopback.